# VisualForce: Display a list of related Users for a User

Tags: apex, visualforce, lookup, user, related-list

I have created a custom lookup field on the User object. This lookup field is of the User type and the idea is that each User would have a *manager* assigned to them.

**Custom Lookup field details**

**Field Label** FOO Manager

**Field Name** FOO_Manager

**API Name** FOO_Manager__c

**Data Type** Hierarchy

**Object Name** User

**Child Relationship Name** FOO_Managers

I created a VF page as follows:

```
<apex:page standardController="User">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Foo Title">
        <b>Foo Manager <i>{!$User.FirstName}</i></b>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:relatedList list="FOO_Managers" title="Related FOOs"/>
</apex:page>
```

Unfortunately, on the page I am getting a blank page. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. According to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_relatedList.htm) from the VisualForce docs regarding related lists, the `list` attribute should contain the following:

> The related list to display. This does not need to be on an object's page layout. To specify this value, use the name of the child relationship to the related object. For example, to display the Contacts related list that would normally display on an account detail page, use list="Contacts".

What am I not understanding here?

**-- EDIT --**

**According to the first answer, the above is not possible. An alternative has been proposed as follows:**

```
<apex:page standardController="User">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Foo Title">
        <b>Manager <i>{!$User.FirstName}</i></b>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!User.FOO_Managers__r}" var="u">
            <apex:column value="{!u.Name}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Data has been ensured to be correct, where the `$User` is the FOO Manager of User `u` (and `u` would have its FOO Manager lookup field populated by `$User`). It seems however that I am getting a blank result as shown below.

[image]

It seems that an entry is being listed, but no data can be seen. Is it possible that viewing permission issues can affect the view here?

**-- FINAL EDIT --**

The problem is solved by specifying the ID of the current user in the page URL. Indeed, this can (and ideally will) also be achieved programatically.

For example: /apex/MyVFPage?Id=ID_OF_MANAGER

Comment: There is a standard field on the User object called Manager. Why didn't you use that?

Comment: It's being used for something else already.

Comment: You forgot to include the Id of the User in the URL (see my answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The User object does not support Related Lists, so **this is not possible using apex:relatedList**.

As a side note, when you are using `apex:relatedList` with Custom Relationships, you need to include `__r` in the relationship name. So your example should be:

```
<apex:relatedList list="FOO_Managers__r" title="Related FOOs"/>
```

**To answer your question** on how to display a table of related Users, you can create your own Related List using `apex:pageBlockTable`.

**FOR A SPECIFIED USER**

```
<apex:page standardController="User">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Foo Title">
        <b>Foo Manager <i>{!User.FirstName}</i></b>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!User.FOO_Managers__r}" var="u">
        <apex:column value="{!u.FirstName}" />
        <apex:column value="{!u.LastName}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Visiting the page, you must include the Id of the User (Manager) which you want to see the subordinates (related users). ex: `/apex/MyVFPage?Id=ID_OF_MANAGER`

[image]

Comment: Just like a Contact would contain a lookup field for the Account, my User would contain a lookup field known as FOO Manager that points to another User. Now, with that in mind, I want to present a list of FOOs for a particular FOO Manager, just like one would present a list of Contacts for a particular Account.

Comment: I see. So how can I present such a list in this case instead of using a related list?

Comment: you can create your own related list table (see my edited post)

Comment: So `{!User.FOO_Managers__r}` is the relationship between a User (FOO Manager) and the User's FOOs? I thought the `__r` reference only applies for custom objects. The FOO_Manager lookup points to a User object not a custom object. I am confused because I specified the Child Relationship Name for the lookup as `FOO_Managers`.

Comment: In this case, `FOO_Managers__r` isn't a Custom Object, it is a Custom Relationship Field. Sorry for the confusion, in my answer I should have said "Custom Relationship" instead of "Custom Object"

Comment: To elaborate: Alice is the $User and Bob is $User_FOO. Bob's FOO_Manager lookup is populated by Alice.

Therefore, if I am logged as $User and apply the above code, I should be able to see Bob listed as a FOO. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, give it a try.

Comment: It seems that it didn't work quite as intended. Please view my edited question above for more information and thank you as always for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71481/discussion-between-bob-lopez-and-jablesauce).

Comment: Specifying the ID in the URL solves this problem. Thank you!